# How to get total number of row by using this function php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to get total number of row by using this function php mysql ?

i use this code for display data from mysql. It's work good,

Buy i want to know can i get total number of row by using this code ?

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line of  code

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$number_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); // this will return the number of rows found by the $result query. 
echo $number_of_rows;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this `mysql_num_rows ($result)`